# How do you open up Chromium browser without it opening up a second instance? (not opening as a pinned tab on taskbar) [Windows]

Tags: windows, windows-10, chromium

Here, the left Chromium is pinned. The right chromium doesn't exist prior to launching the program. When I launch the program using the pinned left Chromium, it opens up a Chromium as a different program/second instance (the right Chromium) instead of on the left pinned Chromium as expected.

[image]

Here are my taskbar settings

[image]

Comment: Please provide your Taskbar settings

Comment: @Ramhound Taskbar settings: https://i.imgur.com/J4ouePo.png